# syntax to include Jenkins pipeline optional argument

Tags: powershell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline, powershell-core

I currently have  a sample pipeline that works but in the Jenkins output does not return the confirmation that the script worked.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
     environment {
        CRED_APP_CATALOG =  credentials('id-app-tenant')
    }
    stages {
       
        stage('ConnectToApp'){
            
            steps {
                script{
                    pwsh '''
                        $cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $env:CRED_APP_CATALOG_USR , $(convertto-securestring $env:CRED_APP_CATALOG_PSW -asplaintext -force)
                        Connect-PnPOnline -Url  $env:app_catalog_path -Credentials $cred 
                        Add-PnPApp -Path "./sharepoint/solution/samplesolution.sppkg" -Publish -Overwrite
                    '''

                }
               
            }
        }
       

    }
}
```

I know I need to add the returnStdout from [pwsh script](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#pwsh-powershell-core-script)  some where, but I cant seem to find the syntax any where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the syntax to use:

```java
pwsh returnStdout: true, script: '''
    $cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $env:CRED_APP_CATALOG_USR , $(convertto-securestring $env:CRED_APP_CATALOG_PSW -asplaintext -force)
    Connect-PnPOnline -Url  $env:app_catalog_path -Credentials $cred 
    Add-PnPApp -Path "./sharepoint/solution/samplesolution.sppkg" -Publish -Overwrite
'''
```

Alternatively you may use parentheses:

```java
pwsh( returnStdout: true, script: '''
    $cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $env:CRED_APP_CATALOG_USR , $(convertto-securestring $env:CRED_APP_CATALOG_PSW -asplaintext -force)
    Connect-PnPOnline -Url  $env:app_catalog_path -Credentials $cred 
    Add-PnPApp -Path "./sharepoint/solution/samplesolution.sppkg" -Publish -Overwrite
''')
```

With both syntaxes, you may store the output in a variable for further processing:

```java
def stdout = pwsh returnStdout: true, script: '''
    $cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $env:CRED_APP_CATALOG_USR , $(convertto-securestring $env:CRED_APP_CATALOG_PSW -asplaintext -force)
    Connect-PnPOnline -Url  $env:app_catalog_path -Credentials $cred 
    Add-PnPApp -Path "./sharepoint/solution/samplesolution.sppkg" -Publish -Overwrite
'''

echo stdout
```

Comment: thanks for some reason i am still not getting the output of the mult-line script on the console,
Also syntax 3 gives me an error.

Comment: @adeniran827 I've fixed syntax 3.